# mysql: find column data size on disk

Tags: mysql, myisam

I have fairly large `MyISAM` table with `longtext` field in it

Table size is somewhat 16GB.

I need to know if clearing this column in old records helps to keep table small

I can retrieve table wise `Data_length` using `information_schema.tables`

Is there a way to find `Data_length` just for this one column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you find the sum of the lengths the LONGTEXT column of all rows

```
SELECT SUM(field_length) TotalFieldLength FROM
(SELECT LENGTH(LongTextColumnName) field_length FROM mydb.mytable) A;
```

Once you delete the rows you want, just compress the file

You can do it in a single command

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE mydb.mytable;
```

or in stages

```
CREATE TABLE mydb.mytablenew LIKE mydb.mytable;
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytablenew DISABLE KEYS;
INSERT INTO mydb.mytablenew SELECT * FROM mydb.mytable;
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytablenew ENABLE KEYS;
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable RENAME mydb.mytablezap;
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytablenew RENAME mydb.mytable;
DROP TABLE mydb.mytablezap;
ANALYZE TABLE mydb.mytable;
```

Give it a Try !!!